# Occasional IntegrityError on m2m fields using PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql

I can't detect any pattern, maybe 1 in each 1000 edits of a certain model returns an IntegrityError on a m2m field. Most of the times this field wasn't even modified. When a model is saved I believe django always wipes the m2m field and then re-adds the items, right? I saw django calls `clear()` and then `add()`s the items.

My code then fails with:

> IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "app_model_m2m_field_key" DETAIL:  Key (model1_id, model2_id)=(597,
>   1009) already exists.

It seems like the add of items is performed before the items are cleared, which is very weird. I've tried to reproduce it but it's very hard, only happens occasionally. Any idea what could cause it? Could maybe setting auto commit solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, you have two requests racing to commit similar changes at the same time.

1. Request 1 begins a transaction and DELETEs the existing M2M rows.
2. Request 2 begins a transaction and DELETEs the M2M rows with the same where clause. This blocks waiting for request 1's transaction to commit.
3. Request 1 re-INSERTs all the M2M rows and commits.
4. Request 2 resumes, and the delete succeeds without deleting any rows, because all rows that existed when the statement began have already been deleted.
5. Request 2 tries to re-INSERT an M2M row, but the database detects that it already exists and returns an error.

It's possible to fix this by upgrading to the [SERIALIZABLE isolation level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Isolation_levels) (instead of PostgreSQL's default of READ COMMITTED) but at the cost of even more exciting potential failure modes and worse performance.

I'm assuming you're right that Django is performing a DELETE followed by a series of INSERTs, although that wouldn't be a very good plan precisely because it exacerbates this kind of race.

The best plan is to identify what has actually changed and only ask the database to make those changes, because then if you get an integrity error it's because there was a real conflict that you probably couldn't do anything about anyway.